# Unity3D Character Customization

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Здравствуйте!

Решаю задачу уже несколько дней и никак не могу найти решение. Надеюсь найдутся компетентные люди и помогут.

Из названия понятно что требуется. Есть персонаж. Есть одежда. Ну и, собственно, нужно одевать персонажа в одежду. Все бы ничего, но персонаж, анимированный, понятное дело. Следовательно при анимации персонажа и одежда должна тоже анимироваться. Поясню: одели куртку на персонажа - рукава куртки двигаются вместе с руками. Со штанами аналогично.

Теоретически, да и практически, понятно как это делать. Вот только не работает так как надо. Явно что-то где-то упущено.

Сейчас расскажу как строится процесс. Делаю я это все в первый раз так что весь код, который будет приведен, создан исключительно для тестирования и для того чтобы понять как это работает.

Мне 3D-модельер дает модельку с костями, материалами, текстурами и анимацией в fbx. Я импортирую ее в Unity. Выкидываю модель на сцену. Пишу код для управления, настраиваю анимацию и так далее. В итоге на сцене стоит рабочая моделька. Она ходит, машет и так далее.

Дальше я пытаюсь повесить на нее, допустим штаны. Штаны вроде как встают куда надо, но сам меш становится в исходное положение расставленными в сторону руками. как на картинке.[image: Если присмотреться, то можно заметить штаны]
Но притом она продолжает анимироваться, но, понятное дело, криво. То есть веса и кости вроде как встали в новый скомбинированный меш.

Дальше интересней. Пытаюсь накинуть на него куртку.

[image: Куртка]

Тут она уже с каким-то смещением. И меш в исходное положение встал. Тоже кривая анимация.

Теперь я приведу код.

```
void Generate ()
{
    SkinnedMeshRenderer smr = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();

    List<CombineInstance> combineInstances = new List<CombineInstance>();

    boneWeightsList = new List<BoneWeight>();

    CombineInstance ci1 = new CombineInstance();
    ci1.mesh = smr.sharedMesh;
    ci1.transform = smr.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    ci1.subMeshIndex = 0;
    combineInstances.Add(ci1); 

    boneWeightsList.AddRange(smr.sharedMesh.boneWeights);


    /*materialList = new List<Material>();
    materialList.Add(smr.material);*/
    Transform[] bones = smr.bones;//bones.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

    foreach(Transform bone in bones)
        Debug.Log(bone.name);

    //Debug.Log("Elements length : " + elements.Length.ToString() + "config length : " + config.Length.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
    {
        //Debug.Log("i = " + i + ", config[i] = " + config[i] + ".");
        SkinnedMeshRenderer smr1 = (SkinnedMeshRenderer)Object.Instantiate(element);
        Debug.Log(element);
        Debug.Log(smr1.sharedMesh.subMeshCount);

        // Add meshes to combineinstances
        for (int sub = 0; sub < smr1.sharedMesh.subMeshCount; sub++)
        {
            CombineInstance ci = new CombineInstance();
            ci.mesh = smr1.sharedMesh;
            ci.transform = smr1.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            ci.subMeshIndex = 0;
            combineInstances.Add(ci);  
        }

        boneWeightsList.AddRange(smr1.sharedMesh.boneWeights);

        Object.Destroy(smr1.gameObject);
    }

    // Combine meshes
    smr.sharedMesh = new Mesh();
    smr.sharedMesh.CombineMeshes(combineInstances.ToArray(), true, false);
    smr.sharedMesh.boneWeights = boneWeightsList.ToArray();

    smr.bones = bones;

    // Update bindposes
    List<Matrix4x4> bindposes = new List<Matrix4x4>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bones.Length; i++)
    {
        bindposes.Add(bones[i].worldToLocalMatrix * transform.localToWorldMatrix);
    }
    smr.sharedMesh.bindposes = bindposes.ToArray();

    //smr.sharedMesh.RecalculateBounds();

    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, -90);

    //GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
}
```

Собственно вот. Комментировать не стал так как там все просто. Тем более, если вы компетентный в этом вопросе человек.

Собственно, мой вопрос. Что не так? И где? Проблема в том, что может быть что-то не так делает моделлер? Или он все делает так, а вот этот вот код работает не так? Или может быть что-то где-то упущено? Я хз. Честно. Почти неделя на это убита.

В инете все перерыл. Адекватного почти ничего нет. Готовых рабочих сцен не нашел. Пример от самого  Unity под оптимистичным названием "Character Customization" тоже не работает. Но я от туда и взял в общем-то часть кода которую привел здесь. И все исходники, которые я находил, были основаны на этом коде.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте прочитать про Ragdoll. Дальше уже, нужно попользоваться фантазией и воображением.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/wizard-RagdollWizard.html